# Intellij shortcut for quick call hierarchy

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

Is there a shortcut key to bring up the call hierarchy of a method inline with the code, in the quick menu format, rather than bringing up the call hierarchy panel?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you just want to jump to one of the callers of the method, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> is the way to go.
On a Mac, use: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

There is a 'Default Keymap Reference' on the 'Help' menu

Comment: I like this quick window.  Is it possible to map a keyboard shortcut to navigate these items?  I would much rather use emacs keyboard mapping like ctrl-n to navigate down instead of the down arrow.

Comment: It seem that down in the Emacs keymap doesn't applies to this quick window, submit a request/bug at Jetbrains, they are usually very responsive with fixing things.

Comment: Please to update your solution with Mac shortcut. command + alt + F7

Comment: This is frustrating as a Linux user, where Ctrl-Alt-F7 has an ENTIRELY different meaning.

Comment: For Linux replace F7 by 7! or Ctrl+alt+H (hierarchy) depending on what you want @Krease

Comment: All commands have a name and can be easily found and entered via "Find Action..." (which happens to be bound to emacsy ALT-X for me.) It would be nice to always provide the name of the action. Binding it to CTRL-ALT-META-FOOTPADDLE-F is then anyone's own business. :-) All solutions provided seem to end up in a tool window, I can't find the OP-requested code-inlined (drop-down?) menu.

Answer (score 190):

I don't think the inline method call hierarchy exists (please enlighten me if I am wrong).

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> shows the call hierarchy in the tool window
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> opens the dialog to find the usages
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> finds the usages in the same file

Comment: Wow - I am using IntellIJ since 4.0 and I didn't know about ctrl+alt+h  thanks :)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. (Ctrl + Alt + H)

Comment: wow! One thing that Eclipse can do and Intellij can´t...i´m impressed! :-p

Comment: For Macs: `control` + `option` + `H`

Answer (score 19):

To be complete:
for the Mac user

Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: well, on a macbook, its `commmand + `alt` + `fn` + `f7` which is a little absurd for a shortcut key!

Comment: @edthethird you might want to consider changing the default for the top buttons to function keys rather than the Mac functions, because yes it is absurd otherwise ;-)

Comment: Switch default function key behavior: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66887/how-to-reverse-the-f-keys-default-functionality

Answer (score 16):

For Mac:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
Choose "Callee Methods Hierarchy" would be better.

Answer (score 9):

Don't forget you can always do the action name search with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and search for "call", amongst other commands.

Answer (score 7):

- **Call Hierarchy**:

  - macOS: <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
  - windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
- **Find Usages**:

  - macOS: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>
  - windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>
- **Declaration**:

  - from declaration, shows dropdown menu of usages
  - from usage, jumps to declaration
  - macOS: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
  - windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>  + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> 
 
 
PS: Modified terms (e.g. no more `alt`) in newer Macs

Answer (score 0):

**Type hierarchy** can be also useful sometimes (shows the parent and child classes of the current class):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>