# How to get call hierarchy for classes in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

I just moved to IntelliJ from Eclipse. I know how to get call hierarchy for methods (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), however, I can't get call hierarchy for classes (not type hierarchy), when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on the class name, nothing happened, when I use navigate->call hierarchy, the menu entry cannot be clicked (gray color). I need to know where the class gets called/initialized. This cool feature is in Eclipse, so I think IntelliJ also has this too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340622/intellij-shortcut-for-quick-call-hierarchy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do the call hierarchy on a constructor. Alternatively, I've always found a [usage search](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/finding-usages-in-project.html) more useful than the call hierarchy.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>  on a class, method, or field or right click and select "Find Usages". The results are categorized (new instance creation, type parameter, import, etc) so it's extremely simple to find what you're looking for.