# IntelliJ checking one method reachable from another

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I have a huge project. Let us focus on 2 Classes in that project - Class1 and Class2. Let Class1 have method1() and Class2 have method2().

I want to check if method2() is reachable from method1() in any way.

One way is to do "find usages" on method2() and then keep on scanning the calls till we reach method1()  ( or if we never reach method1() ).

**Note** : The duplicate that this question marked to does not gives answer my problem . I don't want any shortcut for the above  process. I need an alternative less time consuming way.

Is there any **other** better way in IntelliJ to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij shortcut for quick call hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340622/intellij-shortcut-for-quick-call-hierarchy)

Comment: do you mean the `ctrl+alt+h`?

Comment: No. I did not mean shortcut. I already know that. I need an alternative way.

Comment: And we're presuming that reflection doesn't count?

Comment: yes , no reflection used

Comment: There is no such dedicated action. You can vote/follow related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrey has posted as comment, I am just putting it as answer.

As of July 2018 , IntelliJ 2018.1 Ultimate does not have this feature.
You can vote here to include this feature for future releases.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179171